# Error occurred during activation of changes after deployment in EM

Tags: oracle, timeout, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am stuck with a error while activating my deployment in weblogic server (version - 12.2.1).
I am deploying EAR of ADF application to weblogic through em and shows a below error message.
Using Oracle database 11g which was in a different domain at different country and my weblogic server installed in other place.

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Timed out waiting for completion: Activate State: STATE_DISTRIBUTING Target Servers States: ms08 STATE_PENDING ms09 STATE_PENDING as03 STATE_DISTRIBUTED ms07 STATE_PENDING
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for completion: Activate State: STATE_DISTRIBUTING Target Servers States: 
ms08 STATE_PENDING ms09 STATE_PENDING as03 STATE_DISTRIBUTED ms07 STATE_PENDING at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateTaskImpl.waitForCompletion(ActivateTaskImpl.java:501) 
at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ActivateTaskImpl.waitForTaskCompletion(ActivateTaskImpl.java:474) at weblogic.management.provider.internal.EditAccessImpl.activateChangesAndWaitForCompletion(EditAccessImpl.java:1729) 
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.ConfigurationManagerMBeanImpl.activate(ConfigurationManagerMBeanImpl.java:435) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at weblogic.management.jmx.modelmbean.WLSModelMBean.invoke(WLSModelMBean.java:531) at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke
(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.invoke(JMXContextInterceptor.java:257) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.RecordingInterceptor.invoke(RecordingInterceptor.java:176) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.invoke(SecurityMBeanMgmtOpsInterceptor.java:65) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run
 (WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.EditLockInterceptor.invoke(EditLockInterceptor.java:135) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:439) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.MBeanCICInterceptor.invoke(MBeanCICInterceptor.java:301) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589) 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.PartitionJMXInterceptor.invoke(PartitionJMXInterceptor.java:431) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587) 
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.EditSessionContextInterceptor.invoke(EditSessionContextInterceptor.java:225) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$21.run
 (WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:589) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:587)
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.CallerPartitionContextInterceptor.invoke(CallerPartitionContextInterceptor.java:217) at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.invoke(WLSMBeanServer.java:327)
 at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit.internal.EditMBeanServerForwarder.invoke(EditMBeanServerForwarder.java:138) at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$11$1.run
 (JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:655) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder$11.run(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:653)
 at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368) at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.invoke(JMXConnectorSubjectForwarder.java:646) 
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) 
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408) at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) 
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source) at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:244) 
 at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:289) at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_12210_WLStub.invoke(Unknown Source) 
 at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1020) at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider$WLXMBeanServerConnectionWrapper.invoke(ClientProvider.java:529)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor549.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider$WLXRMIConnectorWrapper$1$1.call(ClientProvider.java:703) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:284) 
 at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:245) at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider$WLXRMIConnectorWrapper$1.invoke(ClientProvider.java:697) 
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.invoke(Unknown Source) at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider$WLXMBeanServerConnectionWrapper.invoke(ClientProvider.java:529) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor549.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
 at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider$WLXRMIConnectorWrapper$1$1.call(ClientProvider.java:703) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:284) 
 at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:245) at weblogic.management.remote.wlx.ClientProvider$WLXRMIConnectorWrapper$1.invoke(ClientProvider.java:697) 
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.invoke(Unknown Source) at oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.sdkas.general.pojo.model.wls.WLSUtils.activate(WLSUtils.java:285) at oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.changemgmt.internal.WLSEditSessionManagerImpl
 .commitSession(WLSEditSessionManagerImpl.java:345) at oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.changemgmt.internal.ConfigurationSessionManagerImpl.commitTransaction(ConfigurationSessionManagerImpl.java:583) 
 at oracle.sysman.as.wlsc.model.changemgmt.ChangeCenterRegionModelBean.doConfigurationSessionAction(ChangeCenterRegionModelBean.java:787)
 at oracle.sysman.as.wlsc.ui.view.changemgmt.ChangeCenterRegionViewBean._doConfigurationSessionAction(ChangeCenterRegionViewBean.java:713) 
 at oracle.sysman.as.wlsc.ui.view.changemgmt.ChangeCenterRegionViewBean._doConfigurationSessionAction(ChangeCenterRegionViewBean.java:681) 
 at oracle.sysman.as.wlsc.ui.view.changemgmt.ChangeCenterRegionViewBean.doActivateChanges(ChangeCenterRegionViewBean.java:824) 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
 at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181) at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289) at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) 
 at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.util.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(MethodExpressionMethodBinding.java:53) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.broadcastToMethodBinding
 (UIXComponentBase.java:1987) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:183) at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.nav.RichCommandMenuItem.broadcast(RichCommandMenuItem.java:105)
 at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364) at oracle.adf.view.rich.event.ProxyEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(ProxyEvent.java:72) 
 at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion._handleProxyEvent(UIXRegion.java:933) at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.broadcast(UIXRegion.java:117) 
 at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82) 
 at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:111) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.broadcastInContext(UIXComponent.java:364) 
 at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.WrapperEvent.broadcastWrappedEvent(WrapperEvent.java:82) at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent$1.run(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:168)
 at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent._processPhase(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:510) at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.broadcast
 (ContextSwitchingComponent.java:171) at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXInclude.broadcast(UIXInclude.java:115) at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) 
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._invokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:1207) 
 at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeInvokeApplication(LifecycleImpl.java:607) at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:348) 
 at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:224) at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:650) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run
 (StubSecurityHelper.java:286) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) 
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350) at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
 at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:194) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at oracle.adf.view.page.editor.webapp.WebCenterComposerFilter
 .doFilter(WebCenterComposerFilter.java:117) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at oracle.adf.share.http.ServletADFFilter.doFilter(ServletADFFilter.java:77) 
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at oracle.help.web.rich.OHWFilter.doFilter(OHWFilter.java:205) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529) 
 at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529) 
 at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354) at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
 at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.sysman.eml.app.EMRepLoginFilter.doFilter(EMRepLoginFilter.java:729) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
 at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:266) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.sysman.emas.fwk.MASConnectionFilter.doFilter(MASConnectionFilter.java:50) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.sysman.eml.app.MBeanServerConnFilter.doFilter(MBeanServerConnFilter.java:43) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:166) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.sysman.eml.app.ContextInitFilter.doFilter(ContextInitFilter.java:561) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) 
 at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.caching.filter.AdfFacesCachingFilterImpl.doFilter(AdfFacesCachingFilterImpl.java:134) at oracle.adf.view.rich.webapp.AdfFacesCachingFilter.doFilter(AdfFacesCachingFilter.java:66) 
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at oracle.sysman.core.app.exception.EMRuntimeExceptionFilter.doFilter(EMRuntimeExceptionFilter.java:81)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
 at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315) at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649) 
 at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124) at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232) at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94) 
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter
 (FilterChainImpl.java:78) at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620) 
 at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider
 .runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423) 
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258) at weblogic.servlet.internal
 .ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586) at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor
 .run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager
 .runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
 at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

My JTA timeout is 3600s.
I am trying to deploy EAR to 2 managed servers which are under a cluster and machine.

Data source is already configured and mds parition is using as part of deployment.